# Do different clients use different amounts of gas?

Tags: evm, bytecode, opcode

I'm trying to understand clients/nodes a bit can someone help clarify the below for me.

My understanding is that each client implements the EVM in their own way.

Smart contracts are written in Solidity, then compiled(right term?) into bytecode. Inside the clients implemented EVM the bytecode is interpreted into opcodes, and each opcode has a set gas cost.

Do all the clients convert bytecode to the same opcodes? Essentially is there any difference in gas efficiency between clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contracts are compiled to opcodes before they are deployed on the network. You can't deploy Solidity code to the network directly. The different clients only run the code, they don't compile it.

The gas cost for each opcode is defined in the [Ethereum Yellowpaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (see Appendix G), so the gas cost is the same for the different clients (assuming they are compliant of course).

Comment: So Solidity code gets compiled into opcodes, then opcode is deployed on the network. When I want to execute a function on the smart contract the clients execute the function?

Comment: Correct, the clients only execute the precompiled code.